# Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow in OpenCV C++ : Translating code from Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to draw the "path" of several moving objects in a video, and the output will be an image, with the final state (of the moving objects) and the drawn path, [I found a code doing this in Python](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html) (see the "Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow in OpenCV" part) , and I'm trying to translate it to C++, the problem is that I'm new to both OpenCv and Python, I've been successful to translate the first part, but not to draw the lines, here is what I've done :

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/**
* @function main
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //TODO
    VideoCapture src = VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\youss\\Desktop\\opencv\\movingCars.mp4");
    Mat currentFrame, oldGrayedFrame, grayedFrame, mask ;
    vector<Point2f> prevPts, nextPts;
    vector<uchar> status;
    vector<float> err;
    vector<Point2f> corners;
    Mat good_new = Mat(), good_old = Mat();
    int maxCorners = 100,
        minDistance = 7,
        blockSize = 7;
    double qualityLevel = 0.3;
    src.read(currentFrame);
    cvtColor(currentFrame, oldGrayedFrame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    goodFeaturesToTrack(oldGrayedFrame, corners, maxCorners, qualityLevel, minDistance, Mat(), blockSize);

    mask = Mat::zeros(currentFrame.size(), currentFrame.type());
    prevPts = corners;
    //while (true) {
        src.read(currentFrame);
        cvtColor(currentFrame, grayedFrame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(oldGrayedFrame, grayedFrame, prevPts, nextPts, status, err);
        int i, k;
        for (i = k = 0; i < nextPts.size(); i++) {
            if (!status[i]) continue;
            prevPts[k] = prevPts[i];
            nextPts[k] = nextPts[i];
            err[k] = err[i];
            k++;
        }
        prevPts.resize(k);
        nextPts.resize(k);
        err.resize(k);
    //}
}
```

I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me, but I will appreciate any explanation/hints on how to translate the remaining part :

```
# draw the tracks
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    img = cv2.add(frame,mask)
```

Comment: `zip` lets you iterate over two arrays at once, and the `enumerate` adds an index. So the simplest way in c++ is to just do `for (int i(0); i < good_new.rows; ++i)` and then `cv::Mat new_row(good_new.row(i)); cv::Mat old_row(good_old.row(i);`. | `ravel` just flattens the array...

Comment: BTW: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can do it now

Comment: By the way, is this numpy.ravel method? because in the docs here (link below), it says that it returns one value, but in the code above it returns two
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html